# Problem with dividing two functions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, smoothing

Here is my code

```
n := 0.1; \[Gamma] := 1; m := 0.001;yi := 10^(-5); xi := 0; minlna := 0; maxlna := 3

xy[lna_] = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][lna] == ((-n)*(((y[lna]^2/yi^2)*((1 - xi^2 - yi^2)/(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)))/E^(3*(lna - minlna)))^(1/n)*Sqrt[3/2]*x[lna]*y[lna])/m + 
    y[lna]*(3/2)*(2*x[lna]^2 + \[Gamma]*(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)), Derivative[1][x][lna] == -3*x[lna] + (n*(((y[lna]^2/yi^2)*((1 - xi^2 - yi^2)/(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)))/E^(3*(lna - minlna)))^(1/n)*
      Sqrt[3/2]*y[lna]^2)/m + x[lna]*(3/2)*(2*x[lna]^2 + \[Gamma]*(1 - x[lna]^2 - y[lna]^2)), x[minlna] == xi, y[minlna] == yi}, {x[lna], y[lna]}, {lna, minlna, maxlna}][[1,All,2]]; 

xx[lna_] := xy[lna][[1]]; yy[lna_] := xy[lna][[2]]

l[lna_] := (n*(((yy[lna]^2/yi^2)*((1 - xi^2 - yi^2)/(1 - xx[lna]^2 - yy[lna]^2)))/E^(3*(lna - minlna)))^(1/n))/m

Plot[l[lna], {lna, minlna, maxlna}]
```

Here is my problem: the curve is expected to be smooth in this plot [image: l(lna)].

What I have noticed so far is that if I increase n, let's say n = 1, I have the smooth part I wanted. But digging down a bit reveals that `yy[lna]^2/E^(3*(lna - minlna))` in `l(lna)` is the one causing the problem. If I try `yy[lna]/E^(3*(lna - minlna))` or any other power for `yy[lna]`, for example like `yy[lna]^1.9/E^(3*(lna - minlna))`, everything is smooth. What is the issue?